# Incorrect integer value ERROR 1366

Tags: mysql, import

Im trying to load some information into province_state table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/province.txt' 
INTO TABLE province_state 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

[image]

It give me this error:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column
>   'province_state_id' at row 9

. But I only hace 8 rows what could be happening?

This is the txt file
[image]

Comment: can post table structure and txt file. I would like to test it.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an empty line at the end of the text file, or it is the EOF character that is being read as a new line. Just delete whatever is on the last line (white space characters)

Comment: I already delete the white space and the error still the same, dont know what else could be?

Comment: table structure and txt file are in images I dont know if they are visible

Comment: Don't post images, copy and paste the text.

Comment: Look at the file with a hex editor, make sure there's nothing after the last `\r\n`.

Comment: are you sure the lines are terminated by \r\n ? it might be just \n

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/province.txt' INTO TABLE province_state FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
' for column 'province_state_id' at row 9ue: '

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this because mysql setting when you want to insert a new position without having all data?

You can configure your mysql to set NULL if you don't send values. temporary solution (until you restart the server): SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

or you can set it in you my.ini file. Here are mode details: http://webnetkit.com/error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-for-column/